# Synthesizing amino acids - why sodium hydroxide goes after certain bonds

Tags: amino-acids

everyone. In the following reaction, what is it that causes NaOH to attack either bond A or B over all the other bonds available? Subsequently, why does NaOH not continue with bond B once bond A has been reacted with? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: I believe this is a matter of manipulating the stoichiometry and concentrations of the reactants such that only one of them reacts. Note that bonds A and B are equivalent actually. To make only one of them break, I suppose the concentration of the base could be limited.

Comment: Imide carbonyl groups are more reactive toward nucleophiles than amides. That is why hydrazine is used in the removal of the phthaloylimide moiety in  the Gabriel amine synthesis. The second bond, the amide bond, is cleaved intramolecularly by the hydrazide formed in the intiial hydrazine nucleophilic attack on the imide.

Answer (score 4):

The above reaction is a modification of Gabriel phtahlimide synthesis from [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(Vollhardt_and_Schore)/26%3A_Amino_Acids%2C_Peptides%2C_Proteins%2C_and_Nucleic_Acids%3A_Nitrogen-Containing_Polymers_in_Nature/26.02%3A_Synthesis_of_Amino__Acids%3A_A_Combination_of_Amine__and_Carboxylic_Acid__Chemistry):

> This procedure, known as the Gabriel synthesis, can be used to advantage in aminating bromomalonic esters.Since the phthalimide substituted malonic ester has an acidic hydrogen (colored orange), activated by the two ester groups, this intermediate may be converted to an ambident anion and alkylated. Finally, base catalyzed hydrolysis of the phthalimide moiety and the esters.[image]

The reaction you show is base catalyzed hydrolysis of the [phthalimide](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Amines/Synthesis_of_Amines/Gabriel_Synthesis) shown in the link.

The mechanism of this reaction is shown below:

[image]

Both amide bonds(**2 to 3** and **5 to 6**) cleaves.

**References**

1. https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(Vollhardt_and_Schore)/26%3A_Amino_Acids%2C_Peptides%2C_Proteins%2C_and_Nucleic_Acids%3A_Nitrogen-Containing_Polymers_in_Nature/26.02%3A_Synthesis_of_Amino__Acids%3A_A_Combination_of_Amine__and_Carboxylic_Acid__Chemistry
2. https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Amines/Synthesis_of_Amines/Gabriel_Synthesis

Comment: Yes, but why that particular bond (either A or B)? Why does the reaction happen at one of those two bonds than, say, at one of the carboxylate esters, for example? What makes the resulting intermediate more stable at A or B than anywhere else?

Comment: The esters are hydrolyzed also, in your reaction scheme. The scheme shows both esters being cleaved, along with one of the amide bonds. Your question is really about why is one amide bond cleaved in the imide, rather than both